# Why I can't login in my linux using my account?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, xfce, desktop-environment

I had recently wanted to use xfce instead of gnome, so I just uninstalled gnome and installed xfce, with lightdm, later I couldn't login in my work account but was able to login in another account of mine. Later I had to uninstall xfce and lightdm, but still I couldn't login in my account using GUI, when I try to enter my password and username, it goes in the loop once again...

This only happens with my work account, but on the otherhand when I try to login with my normal account it just works...

I have debian 11.2 installed in my laptop, and gnome version is 3.38.6 installed.

Any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: Can you login in a tty?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan yeah I can login in a tty,